# Overlord runs the wrong version

Tags: overlord

Every time I try to run Overlord on Steam, Overlord: Raising Hell runs, and I honestly don't know what to do.

I have already tried to verify the cache, and have also performed a clean reinstall of both games. When I run Raising hell, it simply runs Raising hell, as expected.

How do I run the original Overlord with Overlord: Raising Hell installed?

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Joachim's comment.

Answer (score 1):

If both the base game and its expansion are installed, either shortcut will open Raising Hell. **This doesn't matter, since the expansion content is accessed through the main game.**

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/2arehi/overlord_and_overlord_raising_hell_which_should_i/)

Answer (score -1):

The Raising Hell is an expansion (what is nowadays called a DLC).

To play the base game without the expansion, you need to uninstall the expansion.

Answer (score -2):

The Overlord: Raising Hell app contains the base game within it, that's why Steam doesn't even let you launch the Overlord app. You can safely play the original game through the Raising Hell version.